# Who is the oldest player who was drafted in the NBA?

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba, draft

I would like to know who the oldest player was that ever got drafted into the NBA?

Answer (score 2):

Bernard James was 27 years of age when he was drafted as the 33rd overall pick in the 2012 NBA draft by the Cleveland Cavaliers<sub>[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_James)</sub>. He is credited for being the "oldest collegian selected in the past 20 years" since Dikembe Mutombo<sub>[(2)](http://deadspin.com/5922248/why-bernard-james-should-be-your-new-favorite-nba-player)</sub>.